# Offline cache - html5

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, cache-manifest

Ok I have a problem with my cache, and just can't figure it out D:

Every time I try to reload the page (To get cache), I get this error: `Application Cache Error event: Failed to commit new cache to storage`?

Someone who know why this doesn't work?

Links (In case you want to see yourself):

- [Index.php](http://sloganator.org/m2/)
- [Cache file](http://sloganator.org/m2/offline.cache)
- .htaccess: `AddType text/cache-manifest cache`

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors from my browser - it shows `Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://sloganator.org/m2/offline.cache` when I refresh.

Comment: Uhm, must be my chrome then D:

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Yup, thats my chrome, just tried to open it in an incognito window, and that works? Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Seems like it's a localized issue - sorry don't think I can be of much help.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll k, but thx anyway :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using Chrome. Your application cache might be broken. Try clearing it but entering the following to address bar:

```
chrome://appcache-internals/
```

Comment: For some reason, I can't remove it? D:

Comment: And it only shows my localhost? (Tested it at my localhost first, untill I found out, that you couldn't do that)

Answer (score 2):

Some files in you cache-manifest don't exist (404).

According to the spec. if not all files can be retrieved the new cache will not be used/committed.

Comment: Anything should exist, and does (Wish it was just that easy)? Try go check out my cache file D: [Cache](http://sloganator.org/m2/offline.cache)

Comment: And it works in anyother browser, and incognito window D: (Just not my standard chrome window)

Comment: If I remember correctly you had a `/` in front of every entry, which would result in an 404 for those files.

Comment: try changing your html to `manifest="offline.cache?v=2"`. And try adding a querystring to the url itself too (http://sloganator.org/m2/?v=2), to make sure this is not any caching issue.